# Vertical alignment of limits in sums

Tags: math-mode, alignment, subscripts, mathtools, substack

I try to find a solution to align the subscript limits of three subsequent sums for my thesis.

The code for the problem looks like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    $ 
    \sum\limits_{\substack{e^\mathrm{r}\nu^\mathrm{r}\neq e^\mathrm{g}\nu^\mathrm{i},\\ e^\mathrm{f}\nu^\mathrm{f}}} \sum\limits_{e^\mathrm{s},e^\mathrm{s^\prime}\neq e^\mathrm{r}} \sum\limits_{k,k^\prime}
    $
\end{document}
```

[image: starting point]

I already looked at some solutions provided by the community and used `\strut` to somehow align the limits.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    $ 
    \sum\limits_{\substack{\strut e^\mathrm{r}\nu^\mathrm{r}\neq e^\mathrm{g}\nu^\mathrm{i},\\ e^\mathrm{f}\nu^\mathrm{f}}} \sum\limits_{\strut e^\mathrm{s},e^\mathrm{s^\prime}\neq e^\mathrm{r}} \sum\limits_{\strut k,k^\prime}
    $
\end{document}
```

[image: strut]

Here, the vertical space between the sublimit and the sum symbol is to big. So my question is, if there is either a way to shift the limit closer to the symbol or an alternative approach for better alignment of the sublimit.

**PS:** I also found some solutions using `\adjustlimits` or `\vphantom`, but they are somehow not working in combination with `\substack` ...

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the `\vphantom` command and found a solution for my problem:

I created a *fake* `\substack` environment for each limit of the sums and used `\vphantom` to align the limits.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$
    \sum\limits_{\substack{e^\mathrm{r}\nu^\mathrm{r}\neq e^\mathrm{g}\nu^\mathrm{i}, \vphantom{e^\mathrm{s^\prime}} \\ e^\mathrm{f}\nu^\mathrm{f}}}
    \sum\limits_{\substack{e^\mathrm{s},e^\mathrm{s^\prime}\neq e^\mathrm{r} \\ \vphantom{e^\mathrm{f}}}}
    \sum\limits_{\substack{k,k^\prime \vphantom{e^\mathrm{s^\prime}} \\ \vphantom{e^\mathrm{f}}}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image: \vphantom]